# What meant by link change in network driver does this means TX to RX so there is link change or is it speed like data transfer phydev->speed or what

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, network-driver

Why drivers raise PHY interrupt. Is it this the job of Kernel so why driver part of kernel raising PHY interrupt like

```
   u32 status = //read registers
   if (status & LinkChg_Status)
    phy_mac_interrupt(tp->phydev);
```

above code is in `request_irq(pci_irq_vector(pdev, 0), rtl8169_interrupt,` interrupt context

on kernel.org it says

```
Sometime during startup, the network driver needs to establish a connection 

betweenthe PHY device, and the network device. At this time, the PHY's bus and   
drivers need to all have been loaded, so it is ready for the connection. At this 
point, there are several ways to connect to the PHY:

    The PAL handles everything, and only calls the network driver when the link state
    changes, so it can react.
```

in above statement what is `link state changes` might be? does this mean at one state its TX and at link change to RX?

Comment: the above code is from realTek R8169 driver

Comment: Link state change is when the physical connection change state, e.g. when you unplug a physical cable, there is a link state change (i.e. the link goes down) and when you inserted the cable the link is re-established (i.e. link up). Depending on the type of physical connection the link can be in more states than just up and down.

Comment: According to the RTL8169 datasheet, the LinkChg interrupt happens on "Link Status Change", And in the PHYStatus register there is a bit called "LinkSts" = Link Status, indicating if the link is up or down.

So I'd assume the interrupt will fire when the link goes up or down.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny can u please explain this from data sheet where it says I think u r pointing to this `Packet Underrun/Link Change: This bit is set to 1 when CAPR is written but the Rx buffer is empty, or when link status is changed.`

Comment: what is CAPR?...

Comment: also how Link change is handled in soft interrupts like NAPI poll

Comment: CAPR isn't documented in the datasheet one can easily find. What you need is the programming guide for the chipset.
There are a couple of Realtek programming guides out there which are all quite similar, look up for example RTL8100 programming guide.
There you can also find some information regarding CAPR.

Answer (score 0):

from The datasheet it says its

Packet Underrun/Link Change: This bit is set to 1 when CAPR is
written but the Rx buffer is empty, or when link status is changed.